# Hapijs avoid json validation when Content-type: application/json is present

Tags: elasticsearch, proxy, kibana, hapi.js

I'm trying to receive a json payload on a hapijs server, that json may not be valid, since is some custom format that i need to manually proxy the request to an elasticsearch cluster, cannot use the proxy option for hapijs because i need to do multiple requests to different clusters, for that i use nodejs http library.

Elasticsearch doesn't receive a valid json when doing bulk actions, it receives new lines instead of commas, to separate json objects:

```
{"index":[".kibana-devnull"],"ignore_unavailable":true}
{"size":500,"sort":[]}
```

Hapijs tries to validate the json payload when it gets application/json header in the request and it responds "***Invalid request payload JSON format***", as i cannot remove that header i need to look for another method to allow that invalid json in the route, even if the header is present.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at the docs, in particular http://hapijs.com/api#route-configuration. If you set **payload.output.parse** to false you will receive the raw buffer inside handler which can then be parsed by yourself as opposed to by the framework.